# We have $a,b,c$ and $d$ are real numbers such that $\frac{b + c + d}{a} = \frac{a + c + d}{b} = \frac{a + b + d}{c} = \frac{a + b + c}{d} = r$.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, problem-solving, factoring

> If $a,b,c$ and $d$ are real numbers such that $\frac{b + c + d}{a} = \frac{a + c + d}{b} = \frac{a + b + d}{c} = \frac{a + b + c}{d} = r$ , find the sum of all the possible values of $r$ .

**What I Tried** :- First of all, when $a = b = c = d$ , the $4$ equations hold and we get $r = 3$ as $1$ solution .

For other solutions I simplified to get $6$ expressions as :-

$b^2 + bc + bd = a^2 + ac + ad$

$bc + c^2 + cd = a^2 + ab + ad$

$bd + cd + d^2 = a^2 + ab + ac$

$ac + c^2 + cd = ab + b^2 + bd$

$ad + cd + d^2 = ab + b^2 + bc$

$ad + bd + d^2 = ac + bc + c^2$

Now I have no idea how to start finding solutions for $r$ from here . Can anyone help?

Comment: There are various ways of doing this which don't involve multiplying out the fractions - I have spotted two simple ideas. So give it a go to see if you can spot something easier. I don't think there is an easy hint which isn't a solution.

Comment: The variable $r$ is here to help....

Comment: Hint: If any two of the numbers differ, you can show that they cannot have the same sign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all $$\frac{b + c + d}{a} = \frac{a + c + d}{b} = \frac{a + b + d}{c} = \frac{a + b + c}{d} = r$$ gives you $$b + c + d=ar\\a + c + d=br\\a + b + d=cr\\a + b + c=dr$$ summing all these we get $$3(a+b+c+d)=r(a+b+c+d)$$ Now if $(a+b+c+d)\neq0$ then we must have $r=3$.

Now if $(a+b+c+d)=0$, then $r=\frac{a+b+c}{d}\implies r=\frac{a+b+c+d-d}{d}=\frac{-d}{d}=-1$ (For clarity: since we are writing $a,b,c,d$ in the denominators, we must need $a,b,c,d$ to be non-zero.). Therefore the sum of all possible values of $r$ is $3-1=2$.

Comment: @Subhrajit Bhattacharya , that was the exact idea I thought of , but what if $(a + b + c + d) = 0$?, then I suppose we will get $a = -(b + c + d)$ , so $r = (-1)$ right?

Comment: @SouradipDas I have added for that case.

Comment: Yes got it , thank you for the help .

Comment: @SouradipDas you are most welcome.

Comment: This is a fresh solution. I liked it more than mine.

Comment: @iam_agf Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the equation only makes sense when $a,b,c,d\neq 0$ so you can use this: If

$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{a}{b}$$

Then

$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{x+a}{y+b}$$

So your problem solves proving this property, and the only value will be
$$\frac{3(a+b+c+d)}{a+b+c+d}=3$$

But if you get the case $a+b+c+d=0$, then WLOG, $a+b+c=-d$, then you achieve that $a+b+c=-dr$, implying $r=-1$.

Then the only solutions are $r\in \{-1,3\}$, so the solution to the problem would be $3-1=2$.

---

So to achieve the identity, notice that

$$x(y+b)=y(x+a)$$
$$xy+ab=yx+ya$$
And substracting $xy$ to both sides you get:

$$xb=ya$$
$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{a}{b}$$

The other side is the same way.

Comment: You forgot the case $a+b+c+d=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't consider it. Adding. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the second thing I thought of (@iam_agf has the other). Add $1$ to all the terms and set $a+b+c+d=E$ and you get$$\frac Ea=\frac Eb=\frac Ec=\frac Ed=r+1$$ from which either $E=0$ or $a=b=c=d$

In the first case $r=-1$ and in the second $r=3$

Just putting $a+b+c+d=E$, which should be an early thing to try, also gets to the same place.

Answer (score 2):

We obtain: $$\frac{b+c+d}{a}+1=r+1$$ or
$$\frac{a+b+c+d}{a}=r+1.$$
Now, $a+b+c+d=0$ gives $r=-1$, but for $a+b+c+d\neq0$ we obtain:
$$\frac{a}{a+b+c+d}=\frac{1}{r+1}$$ and

$$\frac{4}{r+1}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c+d}=1,$$ which gives $$r=3.$$

Comment: $r=3$ is indeed a possible value, but your derivation forbids $r=-1$ (you have $r+1$ in the denominator) which is the other possible value for $r$.

Comment: @Jean Marie See please better my solution. I said about this point already.

Comment: Sorry, I had a superficial look to your solution. I was mislead by the fact that you didn't give the final solution $3+(-1)=2$ but you are perfectly right not doing so (in order to give a little little remaining operation).

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to know eigenvalues/eigenvectors, your issue can be written :

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&1\\1&0&1&1\\1&1&0&1\\1&1&1&0\end{pmatrix}}_A\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\\end{pmatrix}=r\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\\end{pmatrix}$$

meaning that $r$ must be an eigenvalue of matrix $A$.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $3$ and $-1$ ($-1$ being a
triple eigenvalue, but the text allows to take it only once) associated to resp. eigenvectors:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\-3\\\end{pmatrix}$$

fulfilling the condition that neither $a$, nor $b,c,d$ are zero (being in the denominator of the initial equation)

Therefore the answer is $3+(-1)=2$.

Comment: Why that particular choice of $u$?

Comment: In fact, I didn't need an explicit expression for the other eigenvectors (see the modification I just made at the end).